# How to write into same xml file from two pages?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-xml

I have `Single.cs` and `Periodic.cs` files, which have `Button_Click` events,  and user should add some information into same file by pressing these buttons. Implementation of `Button_Click` is almost same, this is why I show only one them.

```
using System.IO;
//.........
namespace ModernUIApp1.Pages
{
    public partial class Home : UserControl
    {


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // this is how i get required path
                var systemPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                                   Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
                var _directoryName1 = Path.Combine(systemPath, "RadiolocationQ");

                string script = "script";               
                string path_scriprt1 = Path.Combine(_directoryName1, script+".xml");

                 cur_script.Add(new XElement("Single_Request" + Convert.ToString(num),
                                   new XElement("numRequest", TxtBlock_numRequest.Text),                        
                                                    ));
                cur_script.Save(path_scriprt1);
                num++;  // I use this to create unique name   
        }

        XElement cur_script = new XElement("Requestes");
        int num = 1;

    }
 }
```

Eventually, user can push buttons many times, and this code will work fine if I dont use these buttons at the same time. Because otherwise it simply overwrites existing information. So the problem is to make this  `XElement cur_script = new XElement("Requestes");` global. Or do you have some other ways out?

Comment: Remove your business logic from the UI and put it into the proper layer.

Comment: What do you mean by that, I mean, which layer should exist this logic. And I heard, that my way is quite damp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for help, but I solved problem on my own. I just used tips how to write into same xml-file, this way:

```
XDocument Requestes = XDocument.Load(path_scriprt1);
                    XElement newElement = new XElement("Single_Request" + Convert.ToString(num),
                                                        new XElement("numRequest", TxtBlock_numRequest.Text),
                                                        new XElement("IDWork", TxtBlock_IDWork.Text),
                                                        new XElement("NumObject", TxtBlock_NumObject.Text),
                                                        new XElement("lvlPriority", CmbBox_lvlPriority.Text),
                                                        new XElement("NumIn1Period", TxtBlock_NumIn1Period.Text)
                                                        );
                    Requestes.Descendants("Requestes").First().Add(newElement);
                    Requestes.Save(path_scriprt1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The real issue is that you need to avoid concurrency issue here. What if you have two persons try to update the same file and the following sequences occurs:

1. User 1 open and load the file;
2. User 2 open and load the file;
3. User 1 modify the xml and save it;
4. User 2 modify the xml and save it;

In this case the change made by user 1 will be lost.

To avoid this problem you want to keep the file open until your have saved it. For example:

```
using (FileStream stream = 
    File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    ....load xml, modify it, and save it
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is desktop app. so it is only one person. `using` statement doesn't solve concurrency issue - it solves resource management issue. To solve real concurrency issue, you need to design an application in such way that multiple instances can run. Although, it is good to use `using` with any `Type` that implements `IDisposable` interface

Comment: @user2540812, **T.S.** is right, there is only one person using same file, but from 2 different pages of one program.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void WriteToDoc(XmlDocument doc, XElement element)
{
    // this method can reside somewhere outside.
    // some generic doc loader can load the doc   
    // add element to doc
}

public void OnButton1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with element
    WriteToDoc( mydoc, myNewElement)
}

public void OnButton2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something else with element
    WriteToDoc( mydoc, myNewElement)
}
```

V2

```
public class ElementAdder
{
    public static void WriteToDoc(string path, XElement element)
    {
        // load doc based on path   
        // add element to doc
    }
}

public void OnButton1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with element
    string path = ConfigMan.GetDocPath();
    ElementAdder.WriteToDoc(path, myNewElement);
}

public void OnButton2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something else with element
    string path = ConfigMan.GetDocPath();
    ElementAdder.WriteToDoc(path, myNewElement);
}
```

Comment: Where I should implement `public void WriteToDoc` function? As I know adding same class to project won`t work, or should  I paste it in `app.xaml.cs`  ?

Comment: WriteToDoc can be a static method in some class. You can pass the file path to it instead of Doc and it should then open that doc. Basically, if the difference only in element itself, you can reuse same logic of opening the doc and adding the element to it. The file path can come from some configuration.

Comment: The main problem to give access to this `void WriteToDoc` function from both pages, dont know how to do it

Comment: `ConfigMan.GetDocPath();` - What is this function do? I guess standard libraries don't have it ?

Comment: In addition to use your second variant I have to use `void WriteToDoc` function, and this function must get  `XElement element`, it doesn`t make sense, it works like my current code.

Comment: And If I use external `class ElementAdder`, I must create one instance of that class for each page `Single.cs` and `Periodic.cs` and send that `XElement element`. Or I just misunderstand you.